# Why aren't locked pages counted into the working set size?

Tags: windows, winapi, paging, virtual-memory

The purpose of the [`VirtualLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinAPI call is to lock pages into the *working set* of a process. However, the [`WorkingSet64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx) API inexplicably doesn't count those pages.

Possibly as a result of this, [neither Process Explorer](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic23886_post122660.html) nor the standard [Task Manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/09/11/fun-with-locked-pages-awe-task-manager-and-the-working-set.aspx) count locked pages in their per-process memory usage statistics.

What's up with this? Could someone intimately familiar with virtual memory in WinNT shed some light on this inconsistency, which can cause gigabytes of used RAM to go essentially undetected? (think of SQL Server or VirtualBox)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Ah, that is easily explained: You're using the wrong API. GetProcessWorkingSetSize queries the minimum and maximum working set sizes. Those are **quotas**, not acutal values.</strike>

<strike>The minimum working set size is what Windows will guarantee to keep locked in RAM as long as the world does not end. The maximum working set size is the amount of memory that Windows will allow your process before pages are moved into the pool (they are not necessarily gone, but accessing them causes a fault and re-mapping).</strike>

You want [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT**:
Since it is now clear that you were not using the wrong API (only named the wrong func), I've done some testing (`VirtualAlloc` and memory mapped files, both in combination with `VirtualLock`) on my XP system. At first sight, it looked like you are totally right. Allocating 512MB or memory mapping 512MB out of a 650MB file added 512MB to the virtual size but did not increase the working set. Following with a `VirtualLock(512MB)` did not affect the working set at all!

Then it occurred to me that `VirtualLock` took exactly zero time in every case, which did not seem plausible e.g. for having to fetch half a gigabyte from disk. So, I checked the return code and guess what. Windows doesn't think that locking 512MB is a good idea, and will refuse to do it.

Repeated the experiment with only 64MB, and behold, the working set immediately went up by 64MB, just as it should. So, in one word: "works for me".

Just to be sure, you did check the return code?

On a second look, this behaviour is even well-defined and well-documented. The docs to `VirtualLock` state explicitly:

> The maximum number of pages that a
>   process can lock is equal to the
>   number of pages in its minimum working
>   set minus a small overhead.

With and without locking, after appropriately setting the WS quotas:
[image]

VirtualBox is a different matter, what you see in the task manager is only the working set of the "Interface" program and "Manager" frontend, both of which maintain working set sizes of below 64M at all times. Though I'm not sure what memory it maybe allocates in some drivers, or if they lock memory at all.

I'm currently running 2 virtual machines with 1.6GB main memory each. Seeing how my 32-bit Windows only sees 3.25GB, that would leave a mere 50MB for if the memory belonging to the VMs is locked. Besides, Process Explorer tells me that Firefox alone has a working set of 474MB and going up while I'm typing this (holy...?!!). That does not make it likely that all the memory in the virtual machines is really locked, because such figures would be entirely impossible then.

As requested, here's a shot of VMMap:
[image]

The figures are admittedly funny... the VM has 1.6M total of which according to VMMap 821MiB are reserved and 772MiB are committed, Process Explorer only shows 163MiB and 54MiB, respectively. Something is definitively fishy there, but I suspect this is probably some obscure VirtualBox hackery rather than a Windows issue.

Comment: Oh cr*p, I linked the wrong function... I am actually using [WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx), a .NET property. I wanted to make the question language-neutral, but obviously failed :) I don't believe the min/max confusion is the actual problem here.

Comment: Hmm... [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533), the only tool I know of that correctly counts all RAM, tells a different story about VirtualBox. Namely, that [all of the memory it's using is actually locked](http://i.imgur.com/rlZ5a.png). Perhaps in your case it can't lock due to there just being too little RAM, or running on a 32-bit host? I'd love to see what VMMap says for your two VirtualBoxes.